# Homomorphisms of a matrix ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I have the following question, What are all possible right $R$-module  $(R = \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb{M}_2(n\mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. I tried to extend maps from $n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f_{n,a}(nx) = ax$ and found that these are right module homomorphisms. But are these the only ones like in case of $\mathbb{Z}$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, the entries of the matrix $nx$ are uniquely determined by $x.$

Now, you may want to ask yourself:

> Is there a homomorphism which assigns
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}
> 1& 0\\
> 0 &1 
> \end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 &1 \\
> 1 &0 
> \end{pmatrix} $$
>   that is defined by $f_{n,a}(nx)=ax?$

Comment: Sry, I didn't get what you want to explain from the above answer. Do you want to say that $f_{n,a}$ is not a homo?

Comment: No, the question is can you interchange the action of $n$ on $x$ with $a$ on $x$ to produce the map which I asked you about. You may want to try a few examples.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now what you meant.

Comment: I think the thing to try to appreciate is how scalar action of integers can't transpose the columns. Please consider clicking "accept" if you found this suitable. It is a check mark underneath the vote options. I'm glad it helped!